# Android ListView control rows clickable

Tags: android, listview, clickable

I have a ListView, it has 3 rows. I want to control rows clickable such as initially only the first row can be clickable and after that, the second row can be clickable and then the third row can be clickable. Also, I want to add this; after every row click, an AlertDialog will be opened with single selection items. Just after getting selected value, the other row can be clickable. How can I manage this situation? Please help me.

Comment: What are you using as Adapter..I mean ListAdapter, CursorAdapter?

Comment: I'm using BaseAdapter and after row click, there will be an AlertDialog with single selection items.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the listener in a listview, the function onItemClick receives the position you clicked. You can have a int variable initialized to 0 to know which rows can be clicable.

Something like this:

```
int current_position = 0;

myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
        if(position == 0) //Your stuff (current_position = 1)
        if(position == 1) //
     }
 });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think I should explain my problem with a detailed way.

As I said there are 3 rows and after every row click, I create an AlertDialog.Builder with single selection items.

Your suggestion is well but in my situation there can be a problem, because after AlertDialog opened, user can press "back" and I couldn't get the selected value. In addition to this, incrementing current_position provides user clicking the other row.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a ScrollView with 3 rows to simulate a ListView. After that, you can easily control click event for each rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you show a clear example please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `BaseAdapter` try using `isEnabled` api. Even though this api is meant for separator. You can return false for row 2 and 3 initially and then based on your logic you can return true.

Another api `areAllItemsEnabled`, for which, you have return `false`.

Ref:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()

Comment: I used this way and I really appreciated. But I have a little problem also, I have a header over 3 rows and I can easily control which rows are clickable, but not header. For the first row, I'm calling BaseAdapter.isEnabled(0) and for header -1 is not working.

Comment: What you mean you are calling `isEnabled`? So you saying you have 4 rows and the first one is header. so in that case header is at index 0. Or I am missing something